# Is there a code to keep track of multiplications and divisions performed in R?

Tags: r, matrix, numerical-methods, gaussian, operation

I'm doing a project where we are given the size of a Hilbert matrix, and we are to use Hx=b and Gaussian elimination to find b, and to recalculate our exact solution for x with what we had calculated for b. Part of the project is to write a code that keeps track of the multiplication/division operation counts of the program, but I can't seem to figure out how to go about this. The result is supposed to be similar to what the solution would be for when using the equation from my textbook.

```
    Input code:
    #Hilbert matrix of size n=11, defined by Hx=b`
    #Creating the matrix
    n=11
    matrix1 = matrix(nrow=n,ncol=n)
    for (r in 1:n) {
      for (c in 1:n)
        matrix1[r,c] = 1/(r+c-1)
    }  
    library(MASS)
    H<-fractions(matrix1)
    colnames(H)=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11")
    x<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
    H[,c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)]
    b<-rowSums(H*x) #Answer for b
    exactsolution<-round((solve(H,b)),digits=4) #Vector solution

Output:
    > H
          [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
     [1,]    1  1/2  1/3  1/4  1/5  1/6  1/7  1/8  1/9 1/10  1/11 
     [2,]  1/2  1/3  1/4  1/5  1/6  1/7  1/8  1/9 1/10 1/11  1/12 
     [3,]  1/3  1/4  1/5  1/6  1/7  1/8  1/9 1/10 1/11 1/12  1/13 
     [4,]  1/4  1/5  1/6  1/7  1/8  1/9 1/10 1/11 1/12 1/13  1/14 
     [5,]  1/5  1/6  1/7  1/8  1/9 1/10 1/11 1/12 1/13 1/14  1/15 
     [6,]  1/6  1/7  1/8  1/9 1/10 1/11 1/12 1/13 1/14 1/15  1/16 
    [7,]  1/7  1/8  1/9 1/10 1/11 1/12 1/13 1/14 1/15 1/16  1/17 
    [8,]  1/8  1/9 1/10 1/11 1/12 1/13 1/14 1/15 1/16 1/17  1/18 
     [9,]  1/9 1/10 1/11 1/12 1/13 1/14 1/15 1/16 1/17 1/18  1/19 
    [10,] 1/10 1/11 1/12 1/13 1/14 1/15 1/16 1/17 1/18 1/19  1/20 
    [11,] 1/11 1/12 1/13 1/14 1/15 1/16 1/17 1/18 1/19 1/20  1/21 
    > b
     [1] 3.0198773 2.1032107 1.6801338 1.4182290 1.2348957 1.0973957       0.9895525 0.9022509 0.8298825 0.7687714 0.7163905
    > exactsolution
         1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10     11 
    1.0000 1.0000 1.0000 1.0002 0.9989 1.0040 0.9914 1.0118 0.9902 1.0045 0.9991

Textbook Equation: 
[Textbook Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSi7G.png)
```

Comment: Instead of using `*` and `/`, write functions which call those, and also keep count of how many times they are called.

Comment: Assign `iprod <<- 0L` and then `trace("*", tracer = \() assign("iprod", iprod + 1L, envir = .GlobalEnv))`